# Does anybody encounter a data discrepancy between Final Layout in Presentation Details and Final Renderings in Layout section?

Tags: sitecore-client, presentation

Here's the scenario:

> **Component ID** is in use as a Datasource in both in Final and Shared Layouts in the Presentation Details but upon checking the raw values, it can only be found in the Renderings [shared] field but not in the Final Renderings field under Layout section when Standard Values and Raw Values are ticked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Sitecore documentation:

> **__Renderings** – a shared field where you specify the common layout for all languages and versions of the item.
>
> **__Final Renderings** – a versioned field where you specify individual layouts for languages and versions of the item.
>
> The layouts are stored as XML in the fields, and the contents of these fields **are merged ("patched") together** to create the final presentation that visitors see.

So in your scenario, Shared Layout is merged together with Final Renderings and datasource from Shared Layout is used in the final version of the page presentation.

More can be read https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-management/en/versioned-layouts.html

And here is the excellent chart which shows how Sitecore resolves final presentation (from the Sitecore documentation link above):

[image]

Comment: This makes total sense. Thank you Marek! :)